# NextJs - Apollo - First render is not SSR

Tags: next.js, apollo, server-side-rendering

I am using NextJs(9.3.0) for SSR and graphQL (Apollo).

My app is working well, but when I check what google is seeing, the data from Apollo are not available

[image]

If I am doing a `curl https://myWebsite.com` randomly, I have sometime the content (like google) without the data from Apollo, and sometimes with the data from Apollo.

For SEO purpose, I need to always have the first render (after a refresh) with the data given buy my Backend (Apollo)

Here is my file: `apolloClient.tsx`

```
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { AUTH_TOKEN } from "./config";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import { HttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";
import nextCookies from "next-cookies";
import { uriBackend } from "./config";

let token = null;

export default function createApolloClient(initialState, ctx) {
  // The `ctx` (NextPageContext) will only be present on the server.
  // use it to extract auth headers (ctx.req) or similar.
  // on server
  if (ctx && ctx.req && ctx.req.headers["cookie"]) {
    token = nextCookies(ctx)[AUTH_TOKEN];

    // on client
  } else {
    // console.log("with data get client cookie");
    token = Cookies.get(AUTH_TOKEN);
  }
  const headers = token ? { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } : {};

  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: Boolean(ctx),
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: uriBackend, // Server URL (must be absolute)
      fetch,
      headers
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState)
  });
}
```

Comment: Where's your page code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your SSR doesn't wait for the data fetching.
One solution for you could be, if your data changes rarely, to staticelly generate you pages with data:
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#scenario-1-your-page-content-depends-on-external-data

If you use SSR, make sure you use an async `getServerSideProps` that `await`s your data requests:
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering